# How to configure Spring Cloud Azure Active Directory and Spring Boot OAuth2 together?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-cloud-azure

I've configured [GitHub and Google via Spring Security application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/core.html#webflux-oauth2-login-common-oauth2-provider) and now I'm trying to add Active Directory.

I've added `spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory` and I also configured it via application.properties, so the effective configuration file looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: common
        credential:
          client-id: ##REDACTED##
          client-secret: ##REDACTED##
        redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/azure"
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: ##REDACTED##
            client-secret: ##REDACTED##
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          google:
            client-id: ##REDACTED##
            client-secret: ##REDACTED##
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
```

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig
{
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(
          HttpSecurity http,
          OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler,
          OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
          OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository requestRepository
  )
          throws Exception
  {
    http
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                    .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint
                            .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                            .authorizationRequestRepository(requestRepository))
                    .redirectionEndpoint(redirectionEndpoint -> redirectionEndpoint
                            .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*"))
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
            );
    return http.build();
  }
```

**Now, the Single Sign On option now works only for Microsoft**, while opening URL for SSO for GitHub and Google results with exception like below. It looks like Azure starter overwrites `ClientRegistrationRepository` bean and does not include other clients.

```
2024-02-21 15:20:29.322 DEBUG [-nio-8080-exec-2] [FilterChainProxy          ] Securing GET /oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/redirect/
2024-02-21 15:20:29.325  WARN [-nio-8080-exec-2] [ationRequestRedirectFilter] Authorization Request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.InvalidClientRegistrationIdException: Invalid Client Registration with Id: google
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.InvalidClientRegistrationIdException: Invalid Client Registration with Id: google
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using several OpenID Providers, it is generally easier to choose a main one emitting JWT access tokens and to configure the others as identity providers for it. For instance, you could configure ["Login with Google" in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-user-flow) (if in your case it issues just JWTs).

You could also choose to have n+1 identity sources model: a Keycloak instance (or Spring Authorization Server or whatever) being used just to federate others and as only "source of truth" for your backend.

Also, you really don't have to use Microsoft Boot starter to use AAD as OpenID Provider for a Spring OAuth2 client. You can use just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. In addition to Spring "official" starter, you may use [this other starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc) I wrote to ease security conf with any OpenID Providers (works with AAD, but also Keycloak, Auth0, Amazon Cognito and many others, and possibly with several at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I end up with removing `spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory` and configuring Microsoft SSO via `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` only.

I checked client registry configuration for Azure and rewrote it to Spring Security OAuth2 config. Please see `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.entra`

The configuration works for Microsoft personal, and organization accounts.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          entra:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
            user-info-authentication-method: header
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          google:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          azure:
            provider: entra
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - offline_access
```

Comment: @Jackub, you should probably keep in mind the recommandation to use identity federation on a single OP emitting JWTs. You'll probably find more appealing when you realize that you can't use Google and Github access tokens (and maybe some Microsoft ones) on your own resource servers.

Comment: @ch4mp Thank you for pointing this out. But could you elaborate a bit more about what do you mean by that I cannot use access tokens from GitHub/Google on my resource server? I’m not storing them, and once oauth2 flow is complete, I generate my own JWT token for a user.

Comment: Google and Github issue opaque tokens and do not expose an introspection endpoint (anyhow, introspecting tokens on a remote authorization server is hardly acceptable). Issuing tokens is the responsibility of an authorization server, not of an OAuth2 client, and it is not trivial to do it properly (do you really implement things like signing keys rotation?).

Comment: Also, if you send that JWT to end-user devices and use it a a "session", then you've implemented what is documented at many places as being a worst practice exposing your app to a all bunch of threats. But all that is another subject than your original question.

Comment: @ch4mp Yes, since Spring Security stopped providing Authorization Server feature in a form how it was before version 5.X. We didn’t want to spend time every few months to do security config migrations due to huge API changes. We came out with our own simplistic version of providing tokens for end-users. Yes, we do signing keys rotation. To be honest we don’t see any downsides of this solution for now, it just works and it’s „simple stupid”. Maybe we will decide to go back to the Spring AuthServer again some day.

Comment: @ch4mp I’m also aware of all the issues regarding the “sessions”. For now, we just use short token validity time.